# Express Json Validator Middleware always 404 if the json body doesn't have error

Tags: node.js, json, express

I want to make this application respond 200 and an empty json if the json request body doesn't have validation error, but this app always respond 404.

This application uses expressjs and [express-json-validator-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-json-validator-middleware)

Here is some application snippet:

**Server.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { ErrorHandler } from './controllers/ErrorHandler';
import { user } from './routes/User';

class Server {
  public express: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.express.set('port', process.env.APP_PORT || 3000);
    this.express.use(express.json());
    this.express.use('/auth/registration', user);
    this.express.use(ErrorHandler);
  }
}

export default new Server().express;
```

**routes/User.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import {register } from '../controllers/User';
import { UserRegistration } from '../entities/jsonschemas/UserRegistration';

const { Validator } = require('express-json-validator-middleware');
const validator = new Validator({allErrors: true});
const validate = validator.validate;

export const user = express.Router();

user.post('/', validate({body: UserRegistration}), register);
```

**controllers/User.ts**

```
export const register = (err: any, req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  if (err) return next(err);
  res.status(200);
  res.json({});
}
```

Currently, if it find validation error, it respond as intended (right status code, 422).

How to make this application respond 200 and an empty json if the json request body doesn't have validation error?

Comment: Can you check with a `console.log` in your `user.post` handler if `req.body` contains the data you're sending?

Answer (score 0):

well, i have got it working by removing the `err` parameter in `register` controller.

```
export const register = (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  res.status(200);
  res.json({});
}
```